# Question on left join in SAS: my code is getting wrong duplicate

Tags: sql, join, sas

below is my query and on the screenshot it's how the two datasets look like and what I want to get.

```
**proc sql;
create table new as
select e.*,
b.Openflag, b.OpenDate
from email.sent e
left join email.open b on (b.EmailAddress = e.EmailAddress and b.JobId=e.JobId);
QUIT;**
```

I do know my query is wrong, please let me know if you have any thoughts! Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks pretty close:

```
select e.jobid, e.email, o.Openflag, o.OpenDate
from email.sent e left join
     email.open o
     on o.EmailAddress = e.EmailAddress and o.JobId = e.JobId;
```

Basically, you just need to select the columns that you want.

Comment: Thanks very much :) however it dien't work.. I guess my struggle here is how to join data from open table properly because one sent could have multiple opens...

Comment: @chenha . . . This should return the results you specify in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking maybe I should do a left outer join?

Comment: Is this the kind of "answer" you want for your questions?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want a start looking at the result set from a `full join`.

Example:

A full join of data based on two fields comprising with a composite key.  The field names have been changed (*to protect the innocent - Dragnet*) to reflect their roles in the query.

```
data one;
  input key1 key2 $ satellite1;
  datalines;
123 abc.com 1
125 def.com 2
125 abc.com 2
;

data two;
  input key1 key2 $ satellite2 satellite3;
  datalines;
123 abc.com 1 1 
123 abc.com 4 1
;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    coalesce (one.key1, two.key1) as key1
  , coalesce (one.key2, two.key2) as key2
  , two.satellite2
  , case 
      when two.key1 is null or two.key2 is null then 0
      else two.satellite3
    end as satellite3
  from
    one
  full join 
    two
  on
    one.key1 = two.key1 AND
    one.key2 = two.key2
  ;
```

View of results

[image]

The more general case of selecting all columns from the contributing tables can be accomplished using the `table.*` selector.  Make sure the `coalesce` computation of the key values is selected before `.*`.  Then any overlapping fields, the keys and any satellite columns, will produce a `WARNING:` message in the log.  When keys don't align the fields of the *other* table will contain a NULL (missing) value.

```
data one;
  input key1 key2 $;
  array x x1-x15;
  do _i_= 1 to dim(x);
    x(_i_) = _n_ * 100 + _i_;
  end;
  datalines;
123 abc.com
125 def.com
125 abc.com
456 xyz.com
;

data two;
  input key1 key2 $ ;
  array y y1-y15;
  do _i_ = 1 to dim(y);
    y(_i_) = _n_ + _i_ / 100;
  end;
  datalines;
123 abc.com
123 abc.com
789 pqr.com
;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    coalesce (one.key1, two.key1) as key1
  , coalesce (one.key2, two.key2) as key2
  , one.*
  , two.*
  from
    one
  full join 
    two
  on
    one.key1 = two.key1 AND
    one.key2 = two.key2
  ;
---------- LOG ----------
WARNING: Variable key1 already exists on file WORK.WANT.
WARNING: Variable key2 already exists on file WORK.WANT.
WARNING: Variable key1 already exists on file WORK.WANT.
WARNING: Variable key2 already exists on file WORK.WANT.
NOTE: Table WORK.WANT created, with 6 rows and 62 columns.
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your help, wonder if I can ask you an additional question? So the table one actually has 30 variables, as we are coalesce (one.key1, two.key2), I wonder if there's a way to select the rest of the variables... apparently I can't do one.* because it will include key1 and key2... Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: You can use `.*` if you accept `WARNING:` messages and select the key coalescing prior to `.*`  See updated answer

Comment: Thanks Richard! I was using your code and it worked very well. However as here I only posted 2 tables needed to be join, there're actually few tables. If you don't mind read stackoverflow.com/questions/64083530/… the question I posted, I am not seeing right results as I am joining 3 tables... Much appreciate if you can take a look